# Linking Facebook Page with Smooch's account trial

Tags: facebook, smooch

I'm doing the Smooch API Quickstart [with this video 7:51](https://vimeo.com/198071401), however, when i have to confirm in the step 3 (Confirm integration) i got this kind of error message:

[image: Confirm integration]

NOTE: The video hit "Save Changes" but now the UI have "Connect Facebook Page" instead. The two previos steps are the same.

Comment: i guess it would be better to contact the creator of that tutorial, or the creator of the smooch api. this looks quite specific.

Comment: @lushch of the help center they suggest posting here with the smooch tag.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution.

The problem was the Facebook user's role that it was as "Editor" then i request to one of the admin users to assign the admin role for my user and finally works.